# Why can an exception occur when initializing the constructor list parameter？

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <typename T>
Blob<T>::Blob(std::initializer_list<T> il) try :
data(std::make_shared<std::vector<T>>(il)) {
/* empty body */
} catch(const std::bad_alloc &e) { handle_out_of_memory(e); }
```

C ++ Primer fifth edition 779 page said

> Notice that the keyword try appears before the colon that begins the constructor
>   initializer list and before the curly brace that forms the (in this case empty) constructor
>   function body. The catch associated with this try can be used to handle exceptions
>   thrown either from within the member initialization list or from within the constructor
>   body.
>   It is worth noting that an exception can happen while initializing the constructor’s
>   parameters. Such exceptions are not part of the function try block. The function try
>   block handles only exceptions that occur once the constructor begins executing. As
>   with any other function call, if an exception occurs during parameter initialization, that
>   exception is part of the calling expression and is handled in the caller’s context.

I am confused and can not think of a situation where/when it happens，can anyone give me
an example?

Comment: Taken out of context like that, it's hard to know what they meant by "initializing a constructor's parameters". The parameters to *any* function call must be evaluated, which can lead to exceptions, especially if those parameters are derived from function calls.

Comment: @MarkRansom I have added more information, now I think you can know what they mean.

Comment: You should change the title, it seems you are asking about initialization of members via the member initializer list, and not about parameter initialization. The class members are not parameters

Comment: @M.M My statement is almost the same as the book，delete the word 'list'? I can't think out a more accurate expression.

Comment: @K.Robert the main point is that you are using the word "parameter" when apparently you are not talking about parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
struct S
{
    S(char *);
};

int main()
{
    S s(new char[0x7FFFFFFF]);
}
```

The `new char[0x7FFFFFFF]` might throw an out-of-memory exception.

Comment: This code can't compile: error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes in VS2015, tested in VS2010 same as well.

Comment: Error: the size of an array in 'new' must be non-negative in VS2010 too.

Comment: @H.DJEMAI add an empty function body

Answer (score 0):

If you run out of memory while initialising the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing can occur when an exception is throw in a constructor call; either implicit or explicit.

For example:

```
class spam {
  public:
     spam(int eggs) {
        throw std::exception();
     }
};

class foo {
  public:
    spam unused;
    const int q;
    foo() try : unused(1), q(123) {

    } catch(std::exception& e) { 
      std::cout << "spamspamspam\n";
    }
};

int main() {
   try {
      foo f; // exception thrown
   } catch (std::exception& e) {
      std::cout << "It didn't stop there!\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Prints "spamspamspam\n It didn't stop there!\n" on the terminal and then exits with an abort.  Note that the exception can be caught, but it continues to propagate afterwards.

This is because any members that were to be initialized after the thrower are in fact **not** initialized, and const members or references (like *const int q* in my example) are syntactically impossible to initialize at a later point.  So the answer is to abort the constructor call entirely.

Comment: thx, you help understand why the second exception happened. Both the first and the second exception don't happen while initializing the constructor’s parameters, although one function try block can't solve the problem. It is of great help, I hope you won't delete the answer.